Share drive with Windows 11 inside LXC
I am installing a Windows VM using LXD using these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#1-overview. They worked fine for me so far.
However, I fail to share a drive with my Windows 11 VM.
I have tried following commands:
lxc config device add win11 foobar disk source=/home/foo/test/ path=C:\\Users\\bar\\Desktop\\test

and:
lxc config device add win11 foo disk source=/home/foo/test/ path=/c/Users/david/Desktop/test

This should work as the kernel is shared.
Additional information
lxc config show returns the following after above commands:
architecture: x86_64
config:
  limits.cpu: "4"
  limits.memory: 8GiB
  volatile.cloud-init.instance-id: xxx
  volatile.eth0.host_name: xxxxxxxxxxx
  volatile.eth0.hwaddr: xxx
  volatile.last_state.power: RUNNING
  volatile.uuid: xxx
  volatile.uuid.generation: xxx
  volatile.vsock_id: "xxxxxxxxxx"
devices:
  foobar:
    path: C:\Users\janedoe\Desktop\test
    source: /home/johndoe/test/
    type: disk
  foo:
    path: /c/Users/janedoe/Desktop/test
    source: /home/johndoe/test/
    type: disk
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    size: 80GiB
    type: disk
  vtpm:
    path: /dev/tpm0
    type: tpm
ephemeral: false
profiles:
- default
stateful: false
description: ""

These are my first experiments with LXD/LXC. Hence, instructions for absolute beginners would be much appreciated.

You can solve this as follows:

Run lxc config device add win11 itunes disk source=/home/johndoe/Music/iTunes path=itunes on the host.
On the guest system (Windows VM) install the latest virtIO win guest-tools from here. These guest-tools are referenced in this GitHub project itself referenced here: Fedora project: Creating Windows virtual machines using virtIO drivers

Installing these guest-tools will creates a new service on your guest system, which you should add to start-up type Automatic and start:

This service will translate the path of the device you added in the first step to something windows understands resulting in the following drive appearing in your explorer:

which is the drive you shared with your guest system/Windows VM.
On your host system lxc config show should show:
architecture: x86_64
config:
  limits.cpu: "4"
  limits.memory: 8GiB
  volatile.cloud-init.instance-id: xxx
  volatile.eth0.host_name: xxx
  volatile.eth0.hwaddr: xxx
  volatile.last_state.power: RUNNING
  volatile.last_state.ready: "false"
  volatile.uuid: xxx
  volatile.uuid.generation: xxx
  volatile.vsock_id: "xxx"
devices:
  itunes:
    path: itunes
    source: /home/johndoe/Music/iTunes
    type: disk
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    size: 80GiB
    type: disk
  vtpm:
    path: /dev/tpm0
    type: tpm
ephemeral: false
profiles:
- default
stateful: false
description: ""

EDIT: It seems as if for a windows guest system this only works for one mount. I, thus, only share one directory with the guest and move all files I need to that directory.
Additional sources I used:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/help-me-setup-a-host-directory-sharing-with-windows-vm/19192
https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io/howto-windows.html

